# Exception thrown and not caught In Polyfill.js - angular4 with IE 11

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular4-router

I have created an angular application , the app works fine in other Browsers and 
getting a below error in IE11,IE10.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: uncomment all the commented imports in polyfills.ts and build it again

Comment: @CruelEngine  .. Thanks man its working fine